# I can not listen from emitting child to parent communication

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have two components App.vue and ModalWindow.vue

I am trying to open a modal window (ModalWindow.vue) in the parent component App.vue
on button click with event "toggle" which calls the function "toggleModal"

But I can't please tell me where is my mistake

***This.is my App.vue***

```html
<button @toggle="toggleModal">  
  <svg class="user-nav__icon"  >
    <use xlink:href="@/img/sprite.svg#icon-chat"></use>
  </svg>
</button>

<script>
import ModalWindow from '../UI/ModalWindow.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ModalWindow
  },
  mixins: [ModalWindow],
  methods: {  
     toggleModal() {
     this.toggle();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***AND THIS IS MY ModalWindow.vue***

```html
<template>
<template>
    <div>        
        <transition name="fade">
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal-message">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2>Vue Modal</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Modals are so easy in Vue.js!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        name: 'ModalWindow',
       data() {
              return {  
           show: false         
              }                
       },
       methods: {  
        toggle() {
            this.show = !this.show
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should post all content of vue file , dont need split into script and html content. Beside I think scss doesn't need post here

Comment: it seems that you're not using `ModalWindow` in app.vue

Comment: i edited .. it not that mistake..it mistake I took here

Comment: please share how are you using `ModalWindow` in app.vue?

Answer (score 1):

no need for the $emit since you are not listening to the emitted event anywhere. I guess looking at your question your requirement needs the mixin mechanism to call the toggle method of your modal.vue.

just below the

```
components: {
    ModalWindow
  }
```

in your **app.vue** add the line

```
mixins: [ModalWindow]
```

and add the below line in your toggleModal method

```
this.toggle();
```

just below the this.show line. You can also remove the ModalWindow from the components object if mixins work.

Comment: able to see any errors?@JustinMoreyl just post your mixin updated code here. Will try to guide you from there

Comment: something doesn't work here, it seems to me <div class="modal" v-show="show">

Comment: yes, I was about to say that. Can you just comment out the core logic of your modal and just try opening an empty dialog. It'll help us know if the mixin works

Comment: <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-message">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Vue Modal</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Modals are so easy in Vue.js!</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: export default {
    name: 'ModalWindow',
       data() {
              return {
                     show: false
              }                
       },
    
}

Comment: @JustinMoreyl can't see toggle method in your ModalWindow.vue?

Comment: @JustinMoreyl Can you put console.log inside the toggle method of ModalWindow.vue and check if it is getting hit (when the toggleModal of app.vue is hit)? If it is getting hit then, you have to check your css classes and the mixin works correctly.

Comment: @JustinMoreyl Nothing is getting logged in the Console.log that you've put?